# Is it true that in a Noetherian ring every descending chain of prime ideals stabilizes?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, noetherian

> Is it true that in a Noetherian ring every descending chain of prime ideals stabilizes?

It would be good if I had this result. As it would finish off my proof that the minimal primes of an ideal $I$ of a Noetherian ring $R$ consist of the minimal (w.r.t. inclusion) elements of $\text{Ass }I$.

Comment: By converge I mean there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t any $n^{th}$ and $m^{th}$ term in the sequence are equal for $n,m \geq N$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes: if $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal generated by $n$ elements in a Noetherian ring, then it has height at most $n$. In other words, the longest strictly descending chain of prime ideals starting with $\mathfrak p$ has no more than $n$ steps. This follows from repeated application of [Krull's principal ideal theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem).

That being said, there could be *arbitrarily long* finite descending chains of prime ideals in a Noetherian ring. Indeed, there are Noetherian rings of infinite Krull dimension.

Comment: In what sense is generated being used here? As $R = 1_{R}R$ then this would imply that it has at most 1 prime contained in it. Which is in general clearly false.

Comment: @user93826 Is $R$ a prime ideal?

Comment: R is the ambient ring. So yes? Am I being incredibly stupid?

Comment: @user93826 You might want to look at the [definition of a prime ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_ideal#Prime_ideals_for_commutative_rings)... ;)

Comment: Oops! Thanks for pointing that out! Never the less, the Krull's theorem seems to be talking about ACC not DCC.

Comment: And in general my ideal may not be generated by n elements?

Comment: @user93826 Krull's theorem gives a bound on the height of an ideal. Think about what that means. Also, your ring is Noetherian, so every ideal is finitely generated.

Comment: Of course. Thanks

Comment: @user93826 My pleasure!