# On Commutative Noetherian Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $P, Q$ be prime ideals of the commutative Noetherian ring $R$(with unity) such that $ P \subset Q$. Show that, if there exists one prime ideal of $R$ strictly between $P$ and $Q$ then there are infinitely many.

I  just study Krull's Principal ideal Theorem and immediately after I got this exercise. I think I should use Krull's Principal ideal theorem.

Can I do something with integral domain $R/P$?

My Attempt : Consider R/P which is Noetherian and integral domain. Hence we can assume R is Noetherian domain and P is zero prime ideals.  If possible let there exist finitely many prime ideals between 0 and Q. Now what to do? Can I use prime avoidance theorem now? But how?

Comment: Does "there are infinitely many" include that they have to be between $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: The wording will be important, because it seems like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/584524/29335) is not consistent with yours, given some interpretations.

Comment: @rschwieb  I think so what you have said about " There are infinitely many " . This is question from a book written by R. Y. SHARP

Comment: @rschwieb yes they have to be between P and Q